# Git diff tool on every commit?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, difftool

I would like to run `git difftool HEAD~3.. path/to/file` and have git open the difftool for each of those three commits so that I can see a side-by-side view of each commit.

How would I go about getting git-difftool to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would accomplish what you describe:

```
git difftool HEAD~3 HEAD~2 path/to/file
git difftool HEAD~2 HEAD~1 path/to/file
git difftool HEAD~1 HEAD path/to/file
```

Want to automate this process? Is it always three commits? Do you want a three-way merge?

**Update:**

If the answers are yes-yes-no, the solution will be:

```
for i in {3..1}; do
  git difftool HEAD~$i HEAD~$((i-1)) path/to/file
done
```

**Update:**

If the answers are yes-no-yes, it is essentially what @ruffin asks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726144/view-full-file-diff-of-x-commits-of-a-single-files-history-thats-hosted-in). See my answer there.

Answer (score 12):

Or you could just run `git log -p` - it does pretty much the same thing that you want

Comment: Not exactly, I believe. As far as I got, the side-by-side diffs are desirable result.

Comment: This is what I usually do to get similar result. My [first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11726664/237105) answer was devoted to side-by-side comparison exactly.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Matthieu Moy suggested much better variant:

```
for rev in $(git rev-list <committish>.. ); do
    git difftool ${rev} ${rev}~1;
    done
```

The OLD version of the answer:

I would say you do something like:

```
git rev-list <commitish>.. | wc -l
```

or

```
git log --oneline <commitish>.. | wc -l
```

This will calculate how many revision you have between your `<commitish>` and HEAD.

Then using this number you can automatically run through the commits to see the diffs

```
c=`git log --online <commitish>.. | wc -l`

while ! ${c} eq 0 ; do

git difftool HEAD~${c} HEAD~${($c-1)}
c=${c}-1
done
```

Comment: I would make this the answer since it's the first and has the gist of it down but it's a little complicated. I fear others who come around won't 'get' this answer if I mark it. Sorry

Comment: I'd say it is the last much more than the first.

Comment: Why count with `wc -l` and then iterate with `HEAD~number` when you can iterate directly on revisions with `for rev in $(git rev-list ...)`? Your version does not work if the history between `commitish` and `HEAD` have merge: `commitish` can be `HEAD~n` with `commitish..HEAD` containing more than `n` commits...

Comment: @MatthieuMoy - you're correct. By the time I was writing this I probably didn't know of forgot about ability to iterate over rev-list. Correcting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  ((j=${i}-1))
  git difftool HEAD~${i}..HEAD~${j} path/to/file &
done
```

Comment: The line `git difftool HEAD~${i}.. path/to/file &` has two errors: (1) standard input is not a tty (2) doesn't show commits, shows diffs between previous states and current state instead. See my answer for fixes.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Corrected for #2, but I'm not sure I see what you're saying for #1 - that works for me, but maybe it's dependent on what you have your `diff.tool` set to (`meld` in my config).

Comment: Well, I checked in textmode (`emerge`, `vimdiff`).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

1) Perform an interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i <commitish>
```

2) Mark all your commits for edit

3) For each commit run

```
git difftool HEAD~1
```

4) Go to the next commit and repeat step 3

```
git rebase --continue
```

The added advantage is that if you see a problem in the review, you have already checked out the commit that you want to fix.