# View full file diff of `x` commits of a single file's history (that's hosted in git)

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log, difftool, mergetool

Say I have a file in git called `filex.code`, and I want to see the *full code* of the last `x` versions of that file with *each changed section highlighted* -- all in one place.  So an `x`-paned commit history of `filex.code`, almost as if I were doing an `x`-paned diff, but viewing historical versions rather than merging from different branches.

The greater `x`, the better.  Crossplatform would be great, but any of the Big Three works.  Being able to edit the latest version would also be great, but read-only visualization is plenty.

Note that this is different from a [simple history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786027/how-to-view-file-history-in-git) of commits to a file, so the otherwise wonderful [`gitk path/to/file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321962/1028230) (or SourceTree or whatever visual git client you love) isn't what I'm looking for.  [`git log -p`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1786184/1028230) also comes close, and its output tantalizingly includes all the information I'd want, just that it's all in a linear, almost "procedural" output format rather than a good, relatively non-hierarchical, visual one like your favorite three-paned GUI'd mergetool's.

(**Edit:** Another really cool option that ultimately still experiences the shortcomings of only showing each line's latest source & a linear output is [`git blame`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458509/1028230), but it's cool.)

So I'm not precisely looking for [setting up difftool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255212/1028230) either, I don't think.  Rather than diffing two known versions of a file, I want to visualize `x` iterations of historical edits to a single file.

Asking too much?  Is this a WTFA (Write The "Fantastic" App [yourself]) situation?

Lesser alternative: Is there a three-paned mergetool that I can trick into displaying the last three commits of a single file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script opens last N revisions of the file side-by-side.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, tempfile
from shutil import rmtree
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE
from optparse import OptionParser
from traceback import print_exc

COMMAND = 'vim -d'

def vcall(cmd, **kwargs):
    if options.verbose:
        print ' '.join(cmd)
    return call(' '.join(cmd) if sys.platform == 'darwin' else cmd, 
                **kwargs)

parser = OptionParser('usage: %s [-n <number of revisions>] filename' % 
                      sys.argv[0])
parser.add_option('-n', '--num', dest='N', type='int', 
                  help='number of revisions', default=3)
parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose',
                  help='be verbose', default=False, action='store_true')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
if len(args) != 1:
    parser.error('incorrect number of arguments')
filename = args[0]

if vcall('git rev-parse'.split()) != 0:
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    cmd = 'git rev-list HEAD --'.split() + [filename]
    if options.verbose:
        print ' '.join(cmd)
    pipe = Popen(' '.join(cmd) if sys.platform == 'darwin' else cmd, 
                 stdout=PIPE).stdout
    revs = []
    for i, line in enumerate(pipe):
        if i == options.N:
            break
        revs.append(line.rstrip())
except:
    print_exc()

N = len(revs)
if N == 0:
    sys.exit('fatal: ambiguous argument %s: path not in the working tree' % 
             filename)
elif N < options.N:
    sys.stderr.write('%s has only %d revision%s' % 
                     (filename, N, 's' if N > 1 else ''))

tempdir = ''
try:
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    head, tail = os.path.split(filename)
    tempfiles = []
    for i in xrange(N):
        tempfiles.append(tail + ('.%d' % i if i else ''))
    for i, f in enumerate(tempfiles):
        with open(os.sep.join((tempdir, f)), 'w') as fout:
            vcall(['git', 'show', '%s:./%s' % (revs[i], filename)], stdout=fout)
    vcall(COMMAND.split() + list(reversed(tempfiles)), shell=True, cwd=tempdir)
except:
    print_exc()
finally:
    try:
        if tempdir and os.path.isdir(tempdir):
            rmtree(tempdir)
    except:
        print_exc()
```

Notes:

1. Vimdiff has a limitation of highlighting diffs in only 4 (first) buffers, but as for showing side-by-side - all file revisions are shown (eg N=20 works great). To avoid the warning for N>4 use `COMMAND = 'vim -O'` to see versions side-by-side without any diffs at all.
2. The script has grown to be too large for SO style, but it is quite bullet-proof now - yet simple enough for an experienced eye.

Comment: I put in an edit with a fix to work on OS X 10.7.4's stock python. cwd was working, but the call to vimdiff wasn't. Not sure why not. Code [here](http://rufwork.com/files/python/diffige.py), in case edit's rejected for whatever reason. Thanks. **Really** good stuff. Going to clean up comments.

Comment: As for feeding arguments via one string to `call` instead of a list: "If a string is specified for args, it will be used as the name or path of the program to execute; this will only work if the program is being given no arguments." Seems as though OS X implementation is somewhat non-standard.

Comment: I've accepted a modified version of your patch, try again plz. What makes it stranger is that other instances of `call` in this script seem to be working fine under OS X. Do `vim` and `git` have different types?

Comment: Works great -- Go figure.  Much cleaner fix in your version of the patch.  Thanks again.